# Which First Order theorem provers are guaranteed to halt on monadic inputs?

Tags: proof, smt, theorem-proving, formal-verification, first-order-logic

Monadic First Order Logic, where all predicates take exactly one argument, is a known decidable fragment of first order logic. Testing whether a formula is satisfiable in this logic is decidable, and there exist [resolution-based methods](https://cs.famaf.unc.edu.ar/~careces/cordoba08/Bib/joyner.pdf) for deciding this.

I'm in a situation where I need to test some monadic first-order logic statements for satisfiability. I realize I will hit theoretical limits for complexity, but I'm hoping I can get reasonable performance in common cases.

Right now, there exist a bunch of theorem provers, which provide fast methods for solving first-order logic problems. 
These include [Vampire](http://www.vprover.org/), [SPASS](https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/automation-of-logic/software/spass-workbench/), [E](http://wwwlehre.dhbw-stuttgart.de/~sschulz/E/E.html), as well as the quantifier extensions of [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) and [CVC4](http://cvc4.cs.stanford.edu/web/). However, because of undecidability, they're not guaranteed to halt.

**My Question**

Of existing theorem provers, are there any who are guaranteed to halt when given a monadic formula as input? Or is there a way to use them to (somewhat) efficiently test monadic formulas for satisfiability?